# Oracle Left join between dates two different schemas

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, database-schema

Totally SQL newbie trying to convert one of my R queries into an Oracle SQL query - apologies if I get the terminology wrong but I'll try to be explicit.

Using Oracle SQL Developer 4.0.3.16 on Windows.

I am trying to join tables ("VMS" and "TRIP") from two different different schemas (schA and schB) based on a date range and a permit ID. I want to do a left join (keep all rows from schA.VMS and only the TRIP_JOIN field from schB... leaving NA in the TRIP_JOIN field when the dates don't match).

A description of the two schemas.table:

```
 describe schA.VMS
 Name              Null     Type        
 ----------------- -------- ----------- 
 PERMIT                     NUMBER(6)   
 POSITION_DATETIME NOT NULL DATE        
 LATITUDE      NOT NULL NUMBER(9,6) 
 LONGITUDE     NOT NULL NUMBER(9,6)


 describe schB.TRIP
 Name                       Null     Type         
 -------------------------- -------- ------------ 
 PERMIT                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(6)  
 TRIP_JOIN                  NOT NULL NUMBER       
 TRIP_START                          DATE         
 TRIP_END                            DATE
```

I have been trying different versions of the below code

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy HH24:MI'

SELECT schA.VMS.*,TRIP_JOIN FROM schA.VMS
  LEFT JOIN schA.VMS 
  ON schA.VMS.POSITION_DATETIME BETWEEN 
     to_date(schB.TRIP.TRIP_START) AND to_date(schB.TRIP.TRIP_END)
  WHERE to_char(schA.VMS.PERMIT) = schB.TRIP.PERMIT
```

I keep getting this error message. I assume I'm misspecifying across schemas but I can't figure out what aspect!

```
ORA-00904: "schB"."TRIP"."TRIP_END": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 20 Column: 115
```

I tried to figure out how to provide a reproducible example but my Oracle skills just aren't quite there yet. Apologies, and hopefully my mistakes are obvious enough without one!

I found SO posts for different pieces of my question but I couldn't find another that quite bridged the gaps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your query is performing a self join on `schA.VMS` (`FROM schA.VMS` and `LEFT JOIN schA.VMS`).  You are not joining on `schB.TRIP` at all, so you can't refer to that table.  Verify your `from` and `join` clauses.  Also, you can greatly simplify your query by using table aliases.

Comment: Downvotes are much more constructive when accompanied by an explanation so newbies like me can improve future questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an error when trying to select "schB"."TRIP"."TRIP_END" because you have not joined to "schB"."Trip"

Comment: Once I have fixed that, is there an obvious reason why I'm not getting NULL values from the right table? I only seem to get the rows where they match, which in my meager understanding is a inner join instead of a left join. Does that seem right?

Comment: It is not right, and it is caused by the WHERE clause, which instead should be in the ON clause of the JOIN. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the advice from Luke's answer and sstan's comment - you probably want something like this.

You have another mistake in your query, which will become obvious once you fix the first one. `t.TRIP_START` and `t.TRIP_END` are dates, but you wrap them within `to_date().` That is bound to cause trouble.

```
SELECT v.*, t.TRIP_JOIN 
FROM schA.VMS v LEFT JOIN schB.TRIP t
  ON v.POSITION_DATETIME BETWEEN t.TRIP_START AND t.TRIP_END  
WHERE to_char(v.PERMIT) = t.PERMIT
;
```

**Edited**: In a comment to another answer, the OP noted that after fixing syntax errors, the query seems to perform an inner join instead of a left join. This is caused by the WHERE clause; it appears the OP meant it as an additional join condition. As a WHERE condition, the filtering is done AFTER the join is complete, and it filters out the extra rows added by the outer join. To get the desired result, the query should be written like this:

```
SELECT v.*, t.TRIP_JOIN 
FROM schA.VMS v LEFT JOIN schB.TRIP t
  ON v.POSITION_DATETIME BETWEEN t.TRIP_START AND t.TRIP_END  
 AND to_char(v.PERMIT) = t.PERMIT                       ----   not WHERE
;
```

Comment: Thanks - I had already accepted Luke's answer, which seems to work, but I do appreciate the more detailed answer (as will others, I'm sure)(+1). I removed the to_date() and it doesn't *appear* to change the result, however, it is an order of magnitude faster without to_date(), so that's sweet!

Comment: That improvement in performance suggests you have indexes on TRIP_START and TRIP_END (as you probably should). Wrapping them within function calls prevents the use of those indexes; write the conditions correctly and the indexes are used! Glad this helped.